# Rounded Corners on Canvas dissappear when Element is dragged to the border

Tags: wpf, canvas, drag-and-drop, border, rounded-corners

i have this code:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Background="#FFADB9CD"  >
            <Grid>
                <Border Name="mask" Height="{Binding ElementName=cnvsEtikett, Path=Height}" Width="{Binding ElementName=cnvsEtikett, Path=Width}" Background="White" CornerRadius="6"/>
                <Canvas Height="100" Name="cnvsEtikett" Width="200" Background="White" ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Canvas.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}" />
                    </Canvas.OpacityMask>
                    <TextBlock Height="23.2"  Text="TextBlock" Canvas.Left="63" Canvas.Top="41" />
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want the canvas to have rounded corners, which works until i drag the textblock to either side. then the corners dissappear. this is a simple recreation of the window in my programm, there i use drag and drop operations to move the textblock. I really need those rounded corners, but i am absolutely clueless of how i could solve this problem!

any ideas??

edit: it seems as if  the canvas is stretched as the textblock is moved to the edge ( because the corner radius changes too!)

Comment: This is just a reach so I am not even going to post it as an answer.  Maybe try giving the TextBlock a margin.  The margin might be transparent and would stop the opaque content from getting to the border.  But since the radius changes I don't think this will work.  But it is easy to try.  Or I would try putting the Height and Width on a Grid Column and Row then putting the Border in the Row Column with Height and Width of Stretch.  Again, just things to try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just thought of another solution..

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True" CornerRadius="6" Background="White" Name="brdEtikett" Height="200" Width="200" >
    <Canvas Name="cnvsEtikett" Background="Transparent"  />
</Border>
```

set the background of the border to the color you want on the canvas and make the canvas transparent!!

this way you don't have to put padding or margin on the elements!

Comment: In what way (besides hit testing) is that different from the solution that I proposed above?  I realize you don't have a margin on the Canvas, and the only reason I put one on mine is because you said you did not want the canvas to overlap the borders rounded corners (which the canvas in your solution does).

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is probably to put the canvas inside the border (I typically put a small margin on panels inside of rounded corner borders to keep stuff from sticking out).  This way, the border will expand or contract automatically as the canvas does (provided it is set to auto height width).

Border can have a single content child, in this case the Canvas with content of its own.

## EDIT

Doesn't this achieve the same thing?

```
    <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Background="#FFADB9CD"  >
            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="mask" Background="White" CornerRadius="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Canvas Height="100" x:Name="cnvsEtikett" Width="200" ClipToBounds="True" d:LayoutOverrides="Margin">
                        <TextBlock Height="23.2"  Text="TextBlock" Canvas.Left="59" Canvas.Top="31" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[**Gong Solutions Drag Drop Helper library**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/gong-wpf-dragdrop.aspx)

Comment: this way the corners of the canvas stick out of the rounded corners of the border! this is way i've used the opacity mask

Comment: So you want the canvas to extend through the corners of the border?  Doesn't the above achieve the same thing?

Comment: no, that's what i don't want them to do, i want a canvas with rounded corners:)

Comment: Well then, if you put the canvas inside the border and put a 3 or 4 margin all around, none of it will stick out.

Comment: yea that will have to do .. it's not a perfect solution cus this way i have to add the padding of the border to the coordinates of every drag and drop operation but at least the corners look good now.

thanks!

Comment: If you attach dragdrop helpers to your drag source and drop target elements, you can get around that.  This supposes that you are using MVVM (as the design patter is what the classes were written for).  Please find a  link in my post above.